Google Apps Script: Exception: You do not have permission to call bigquery.jobs.query
I am using BigQuery Service in the Google Apps Script. And I've also updated the oauthScopes in appscript.json file as following:
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery"
  ],

Here's what I am trying to do, but still get the permission error:
function onEdit(e) {
  let a1 = e.range.getA1Notation()
  let value = "A"
  writeToBigQuery(value)
}
function writeToBigQuery (v) {
  const request = {
    query: `INSERT INTO "${dataset}.${table}"(product_id, value) VALUES("1", "${v}")`,
    useLegacySql: false
  };
  var jobId = BigQuery.Jobs.query(request, dataset)
}

The error is very simple but it seems to not be able to simply fixed by adding the oauthScopes:
Google Apps Script: Exception: You do not have permission to call bigquery.jobs.query. Required permissions: (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery || https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform)

Please anyone could help me to fix this issue? Thanks in advance.
